# initialValues works the first time, but after page refresh breaks the page, REACT/REDUX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I can click on edit comment and it will bring me to the comment edit page with the value of that comment. The problem is if I hit refresh it breaks the page and I get error comments undefined. Now I know this is because the state has been wiped, but is there a way around this that I can wait till the state loads in or such?

**UPDATE:** I have fixed the page from breaking on refresh but I cannot get the initialValues to get the comment value. I am not sure if there is a way to set the state value later on or not. I am getting things like `author` undefined and `_id` undefined and I know it is because I am setting the `commentValue` to `{}`. My question is there a way that when the state does get correctly updated to get those values?

Here is code for the check:

```
function mapStateToProps({ posts, auth, user }, ownProps) {
  let commentValue = {};
  const post = posts[ownProps.match.params.id];

  if(!post){
    return commentValue = {};
  }
  if(!posts.comments[ownProps.match.params.comment_id]) {
    return commentValue = {};
  }
  if(posts.comments[ownProps.match.params.comment_id]){
    return commentValue = posts.comments[ownProps.match.params.comment_id];
  }

  return {
    initialValues: commentValue,
    post: posts[ownProps.match.params.id],
    auth: auth.authenticated,
    user: user
  };
}
```

Here is the code:

```
import React , { Component } from 'react';
import * as actions from '../../actions/comments_actions';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as actionsPosts from '../../actions/posts_actions';
import * as actionsIndex from '../../actions/index';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

class EditComment extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const {id, comment_id} = this.props.match.params;
    this.props.getOnePost(id);

    if(this.props.user._id !== this.props.post.comments[comment_id].author.id) {
      this.props.history.replace(`/posts/${id}`);
    }

    if(this.props.auth) {
      this.props.getUser();
    }

  }

  componentWillReceiveProps ({ user: nextUser, history, match, post, auth}) {

    const {user: currentUser} = this.props;
    const { id } = match.params

    if (!currentUser || nextUser !== currentUser) {
    if (nextUser && (nextUser._id !== post.author.id)) {
      history.replace(`/posts/${id}`);
    }
  }
}

  renderField(field) {
    const { meta: {touched, error} } = field;
    const className = `form-group ${touched && error ? 'has-danger' : ''}`;

    return (
      <div className={className}>
        <label><strong>{field.label}:</strong></label>
        <input
          className="form-control"
          type={field.type}
          {...field.input}
        />
        <div className="text-help">
          { touched ? error : ''}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  onSubmit(values) {
    const {comment_id} = this.props.match.params;

    this.props.editComment(values, comment_id, () => {
      this.props.history.push(`/posts/${id}`);
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {handleSubmit} = this.props;

    const {id} = this.props.match.params;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
        <Field
          label="Comment"
          name="text"
          type="text"
          component={this.renderField}
        />
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">Comment</button>
        <Link to={`/posts/${id}`} className="btn btn-danger">Cancel</Link>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

function validate(values) {
  const errors = {};

  if(!values.comment) {
    errors.comment = "Enter a comment!";
  }

  return errors;
}

function mapStateToProps({ posts, auth, user }, ownProps) {
  console.log(posts[ownProps.match.params.id]);
  const commentValue = posts[ownProps.match.params.id].comments[ownProps.match.params.comment_id];
  console.log(commentValue);
  return {
    initialValues: commentValue,
    post: posts[ownProps.match.params.id],
    auth: auth.authenticated,
    user: user
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({...actions, ...actionsIndex, ...actionsPosts}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(reduxForm({
  validate,
  form: 'editform'
})(EditComment));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like what's happening is that your routing logic is making sure that this component is displayed when you refresh the page at that URL, but your app doesn't have the data loaded that this component expects.

This is basically the same kind of problem that Dave Ceddia describes in his post [Watch Out for Undefined State](https://daveceddia.com/watch-out-for-undefined-state/).  If there's a chance that one of your components will be rendered before the data it needs is available, you should write code to handle that case.  There's several ways to do that, and Dave shows examples in his post.

In your particular case, your `mapState` function is trying to dereference some very nested state:

```
const commentValue = posts[ownProps.match.params.id].comments[ownProps.match.params.comment_id];
```

You should break that up into a couple steps, and do defensive checks to see if a post with that ID exists first, and if it does, if a comment with that ID exists.  If they don't, you would probably want to return `null` or `undefined` for that prop from `mapState`.

Comment: Okay I will give this a try and get back if I get it to work or don't! Thank you for the information!

Comment: Uh... no, the code right now still has the issue.  You need to change the line I showed in your `mapStateToProps` function, as that's the real problem.

Comment: Did you look at the above code not the 2nd section of code. I did break up that part of the code. Let me recheck and see if I can get closer to what I think you mean!

Comment: Okay, that looks better, except that you can't/shouldn't use `return` in front of `commentValue = {}`.

Comment: This does make it to where the page doesn't break but if someone refreshes they will no longer get the initial value. Is there a way to let them still get it?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of markerikson I was able to come up with a solution. In the `mapStateToProps` I did some checks and set some initial values in the case that the state would return undefined. Here is the working code:

```
function mapStateToProps({ posts, auth, user }, ownProps) {
  let commentValue = {};
  const {id, comment_id} = ownProps.match.params;

  if(!posts.comments){
    commentValue = null;
  }
  if(posts[id]){
    if(posts[id] && posts[id].comments[comment_id]){
      commentValue = posts[id].comments[comment_id];
    }
  }

  return {
    initialValues: commentValue,
    post: posts[ownProps.match.params.id],
    auth: auth.authenticated,
    user: user
  };
}
```